# Access "wp site health info" data from plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, debug, bug-tracking, site-health-widget

I wanted to know if a third party plugin can access "WordPress site health info" data. If yes, than what is the correct procedure to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: What specifically do you need: just a summary of the results, or any of the individual tests?

Comment: I'd start by reading wp-admin/class-wp-site-health.php. I'm always a bit wary of including admin site scripts in plugins but you might get away with that, or at least get access to cached results in the 'health-check-site-status-result' transient.

Comment: @Rup just a summary.